# My SQLSHEL changes from 'sql_cookbook=#" to 'sql_cookbook'#' . How can i change it back to 'sql_cookbook=#"

Tags: postgresql, mysql-shell

My SQLSHEL prompt changes from `sql_cookbook=#` to `sql_cookbook'#`. How can I change it back to `sql_cookbook=#`?

Secondly, I just run this command `sql_cookbook=# DROP column 'first_name from ali ;` and it changes to `sql_cookbook'#`. Why? Can you give any solution or information?

I just want to revert back to original prompt.

Comment: What does `mysql-shell` have to do with Postgres? If this is actually `psql` then read [Prompting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING) for what the characters mean.

Comment: `DROP column` is not a valid SQL statement and will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your command has an opening `'` but not a closing one, so everything after the `'` is interpreted as a part of a string literal, as well as the linebreak that is generated upon pressing enter.

The changed prompt is a signal, that you are still in a string literal. The command is not finished yet and nothing has yet been sent to and executed by the database.